# Trouble with CMake and Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am trying to get started with Cmake and started with a simple tutorial found on the site.  The c++ code is as simple as possible here:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

The Cmake file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Tutorial)
add_executable(Tutorial main.cpp)
```

I generate the Visual Studio C++ solution and project files using the cmake-gui.  I am able to build the project, but when I try to run the project I get a prompt stating that the ZERO_CHECK project is out of date and asks if I would like to rebuild it.  When I select 'Yes' I get an error stating: 'Unable to start program ..Path../Debug/ALL_BUILD The system cannot find the file specified'.  I did a lot of searching but was unable to find anyone who has had a similar error.  Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually CMake sets the ALL_BUILD project as the startup project. You should right click on your Tutorial project in the solution explorer and set it as startup project. Then it should work.

Comment: Agreed. The problem is ALL_BUILD does not create an executable so Visual Studio complains when you try to debug that target. This really is not a CMake specific problem you would have the same error if you had created a regular Visual Studio solution and had the default project to some other target that is not an executable..